# How to pass parameters to dynamic screen in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Assume I have several screens as A,B,C,D.....
I am going to conditionally render these screens and need to pass some same params to all of them.
Can I pass a variable to them after deciding which one to render?
for now, I can do,

```
let screen;
if(condition1) screen = <A {params}/> 
if(condition2) screen = <B {params}/>
if(condition3) screen = <C {params}/>
.
.
return screen
```

In this approach, my code is repeating
what I want

```
if(condition1) screen = A
if(condition2) screen = B
if(condition3) screen = C

return <screen {params} />
```

but we cant render a screen like this `<screen/>` coz its a variable, not the component.

Is there a way I can achieve this so I don't have to repeat the code to improve the scalability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `React.createElement` to create the component from the dynamically-chosen view:

```
if(condition1) screen = A;
if(condition2) screen = B;
if(condition3) screen = C;
const component = React.createElement(screen,params);
return component;
```

Comment: Variable has to be capital i guess? const Component https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Comment: No, that's if you're defining it like `function MyComponent`. This is not the same -- it's not using JSX at all. If you want to see proof in action: https://snack.expo.dev/Ax8l6Qma1

Comment: Ohh ok ok, i was also going throug docs after this question appeared...thanks understood 